# Google App Engine error when trying to start web development in Python

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I am novice with python, I have already gone through the basics with command line via using eclipse. Now want to create some web pages, I referred given link and did excatly the same, (http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngine/article.html#app_python) path of my app-engine is (/home/abc/google_appengine) and my working directory is (/home/temp/googleappengine0) so I tried to rug example program but got errors like this

```
WARNING  2011-12-05 07:04:26,319 rdbms_mysqldb.py:90] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/**********/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 77, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/**********/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 73, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/**********/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 682, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/**********/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 571, in main
    root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)
  File "/home/**********/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2983, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
```

Could you guys help me out how should I start with web programming in python, Now I am trying with eclipse with pydev, but still unable to run a program.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have [app.yml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html) file with correct config in your work-directory? If you do have app.yml, you probably are providing wrong directory for `dev_appserver.py`.

You have to run it like this:

```
python dev_appserver.py <directory-with-app.yml>
```

First try to run it without eclipse - run it from your terminal. Then try to set correct settings in eclipse accordingly.

I don't think that google app engine is good start for python novice. Why not to start from something more simple, for example django framework? Django has great documentation and big community so if you run into trouble it will be easier to find help.

Comment: Still same problem, seems some problem with google app engine, I have downloaded it, and thn I am calling  dev_appserver.py to current working directory, actually I have to develop some web application  in  python+app engine, so I thought to develop some basic application and for the same I tried this. Thanks for your kind support, today I ll try django :) thanks.. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

app engine is run not set up correctly, go find the setup tutorial on the appengine documentation.

after that the examples should be able to run.